# what do the 'q' and 'p1', 'p2' mean in URL

Tags: php, url

I am learning how to construct a website. In one demo codes for a demo website, one url is as this:

```
http://localhost/test.php?q=_&p1=_&p2=_
```

I know that this URL will run `test.php` in the `/var/www/html/`. But what do `?`, `q=_`, `p1=_`, `p2=_` and also the underscore `_` mean?

Comment: For reference:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string came up as *the very first result* in a google search for "question mark in url".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. q, p1, p2 are parameters pass to **test.php**. You can name another name,
   such as: name, age, t ...
2. underscore `_` is value of them, you can replace _ by another value (string, number ....).
3. In test.php, you can get value of them by $_GET["q"], $_GET["p1"],
   $_GET["p2"].

Example: localhost/file_name.php?name=abc&age=20

At file_name.php, you can get

```
- $numAge = $_GET["age"]; // $numAge = 20;

- $strName =  $_GET["name"]; // $strName = "abc";
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are GET variables, that you can use in the php page called :

`$_GET["q"]` will be equal to `_` in your example, `$_GET["p1"]` and `$_GET["p2"]` will also equal `_`.

`_` is the value here (after = sign)

See [PHP Reference](http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 0):

q, p1 and p2 are parameters passed through the URL and _ are the corresponding values ...